# Frobenius or Froebenius?

Tags: math-history

There are 1 700 000 pages for Frobenius on google, versus 50 000 pages for Froebenius. The first one seems to be the right one, but why do so many people make this mistake?

Comment: Typical mistake, perhaps because of James Bond (Goldfinger=Gerd Fröbe). The Ö is OE (O Umlaut), so Gerd Froebe. I have seen Fröbenius and Froebenius, but it should be [Frobenius](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_Georg_Frobenius). Same problem with Ä and Ü.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page for Frobenius in German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_Georg_Frobenius) uses "Frobenius" not "Fröbenius".

Comment: Gauss or Gauß?  Mobius or Möbius, or even Moebius?  There are often many different conventions when it comes to romanizing a word or name from one language to another, especially when the original spelling from the time period uses characters not present in modern romanizations.

Comment: @lhf So Froebenius seems to be a mistake, not a convention

Comment: Right, "Froebenius" is transliteration of "Frobenius".

Comment: Consider the case of [Romaji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese), the romanization of words written in Japanese to be written with the western alphabet.  You get differences like つづく (*to continue*) being written as tsuzuku, tuzuku, or even tuduku depending on which conventions to follow.  They are all intended to be pronounced the same, there is just disagreement on how to notate it.  The same thing is happening here, just on a more local level.

Comment: Another common mistake is “Hänkel” instead of the correct Hankel.

Comment: @JMoravitz: The present question is not about transliteration. Frobenius is a German name, and it's written with the Latin alphabet just so: “Frobenius”. Writing “Fröbenius” or “Froebenius” is simply a spelling error (presumably by people who don't know German, and suffer from the misunderstanding that Ö is the German version of the letter O...).

Comment: And the question is not really about math either, so I've voted to close it.